# Expand Sklearn digit size fom 8*8 to 32*32

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, scikit-learn

I have an issue with expanding the size of the Sklearn digit dataset digits from 8*8 to 32*32 pixels.

My approach is to take the 8*8 array and then flatten and expand it. That is, enlarge from 64 to 1024 pixels in total. Therefore I simply want to multiply the values along each row 16 times:

1. create a new array (=newfeatures) with 1024 NaN values.
2. Replace every 16. value of the newfeatures array with the values of the original array, that is (0=0),(16=1),(32=2),(...),(1008=64).
   3.Replace the remaining NaN values with dropna(ffill) to "expand" the original image to a 32*32 pixels image.

Therefore I use the following code:

```
#Load in the training dataset

digits=datasets.load_digits()
features=digits.data
targets=digits.target

#Plot original digit
ax[0].imshow(features[0].reshape((8,8)))
```

[image]

```
#Expand 8*8 image to a 32*32 image (64 to 1024)

newfeatures=np.ndarray((1797,16*len(features[0])))
newfeatures[:]=np.NaN
newfeatures=pd.DataFrame(newfeatures)
for row in range(1797):
    for i in range(0,63):
        newfeatures.iloc[row,16*i]=features[row][i]
newfeatures.fillna(method="ffill",axis=1,inplace=True)

#Plot expanded image with 32*32 pixels
ax[1].imshow(newfeatures.values[0].reshape((32,32)))
```

[image]

As you can see, the result is not as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use skimage's resize as shown below

```
from skimage import transform
new_features = np.array(list
                        (map
                         (lambda img: transform.resize(
                                        img.reshape(8,8),#old shape
                                          (32, 32), #new shape
                                          mode='constant',
                                         #flatten the resized image
                                          preserve_range=True).ravel(),
             features)))
```

`new_features` shape will be (1797, 1024) and displaying the first image will show
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above solution I think the following is a little bit more neater way:

```
from skimage import transform

newfeatures=[transform.resize(features[i].reshape(8,8),(32,32))for i in 
range(len(features))]

plt.imshow(newfeatures[0].reshape((32,32)))
```

[image]